# Ĉu vi faras gravan malsamecon inter plen/ kaj tut/ leksemoj?

Tags: word-usage

Klare, uzado preferas iun por kelkaj kazoj, kaj estas bone koni la fiksitajn uzadojn. Sed, ĉu ekzistas grava diferenco inter, ekzemple "plenkore" kaj "tutkore".

Ekzemple, miamense "plenluno" povus esti egala al "plenvidebla luno", sed ne al "tutluno". Tio lasta elvokas "tutmondo".

Do mi dirus ke "ŝi veturos tutmondon por vidi plenlunon de ĉie" ne estas memsignifa al "ŝi veturos plenmondon por vidi tutlunon de ĉie". Ĉu mi malpravas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mia sento tie ĉi estas ke la voroj klare havas malsamajn sencojn. Ja veras ke en kelkaj situacioj la elekto inter la vortoj ne tiel gravas, sed estas malfacile respondi ĝenerale. Oni devus trakti aparte la unuopajn okazojn.

“Plena” signifas ke la unu afero enhavas alian (glaso plena je akvo.)

“Tuta” rilatas al ĉiuj partoj de io. Mia tuta korpo doloras min.

Tiuj signifoj influos la signifon de la radikoj en kunmetaĵoj.

- plenkore - kun plena koro
- tutkore - per tuta koro.

En tiu okazo mi ne vidas grandan diferencon inter la signifoj, sed "tutkore" aspektas al mi pli logika. Mi kredas ke aliaj simile pensas ĉar ĝi ankaŭ estas multe pli ofta vorto (t.e. **tutkore** estas pli ofta ol **plenkore**).